# check if file exist on remote website without knowing extension

Tags: php

I need to find a file name `_template` on more than one remote server.

The file will have one of two extensions:
`_template.htm`
or
`_template.php`

I can find a file using cURL on a remote server which is easy but cant wrap my head around how to find one or the other.

The code is in a loop and it will search on about 20 different sites for this file, if it finds it just needs to say: **Found it** if it doesn't find any of the two files it needs to say: **None Found**.

- Doing cURL twice takes too long to load.
- Searching through the ftp array also takes too long.

My current code below that doesnt work, in know why it doesnt work thanks guys i would like to know how i can make it work: (This is in a loop)

```
        $template_file = glob("/_template.{htm,php}", GLOB_BRACE);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $client_link.$template_file);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);

        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        preg_match_all("/HTTP\/1\.[1|0]\s(\d{3})/",$data,$matches);

        $code = end($matches[1]);

        if(!$data) 
        {
            echo "No Files Found<br>";
        } 
        else 
        {
            if($code == 200) 
            {
                $filefound = 'Found'.$template_file;
            } 
            elseif($code == 404) 
            {
                $filefound = '404 File not Found';
            }
        }
```

Comment: Check both of them and see which one exists?

Comment: whats wrong with just querying your remote servers for both file extensions?

Comment: It takes extremely long doing it that way.

Comment: @AmalMurali i tried the file_exist() function but it didnt work at all so went on to use cURL and that worked but i couldnt get it to find the file without knowing the extension.

Comment: Are you trying to check if a file exists on a different server? If so, you can send a HEAD request instead of GET. That might speed things up quite a bit.

Comment: If your only access to the other server is via HTTP (curl), then there's probably no way of doing this reliably. The HTTP server could (by rewriting the URL) serve up a different file with that name or that file could exist and the server might serve it in response to a different URL. **In short, there is not necessarily a relationship between the segments of a URL and the filesystem on the server**. FTP would be a better choice, if you have to check for exactly those files.

Comment: @AmalMurali i updated my question with my current code.

Comment: @Kryten i know what you are saying but i dont quite understand, the thing is there will either be a file with that name and one of two extensions or there wont. I know for a fact these files will never have a redirect on them as i placed them there i just need to know that no one is messing with my files as more than one person has access to the server. I would really like to not use FTP as this seems to be something that should be simpler to solve.

Comment: @JohanPretorius - Ok, you left that detail out of the question. So the real question is how to do it faster... HTTP is going to add a little bit of overhead compared to FTP, but not much. The trick is to figure out where the (unacceptable) delay is coming from. If it's just the network between you and the server, then there's really not much you can do to speed it up. Try `traceroute` or `mtr` to see if there's a bottleneck between you and the server. Your PHP code doesn't seem to contain anything that would make it particularly slow.

Comment: @Kryten ok lets say i dont mind it being slow, the main issue would then be to get it to find the file which could have one of the two extensions, that is where my main halt came in. Speeding it up i will debug later as im testing from local now but have a dedicated server the code will be running from eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `glob` function - that function matches paths on the local filesystem. Add a `print_r($template_file);' after the`glob` and you'll see that it doesn't match anything (or it only matches things on your local system).

What you need to do is build the URLs one-by-one:

```
foreach(array("htm", "php") as $ext)
{
    // build the URL string
    $url = "http://example.com/_template." . $ext;

    // now do whatever you need to with the URL...
}
```